# adaptively sized/positioned arrow symbol pointing to the next line

Tags: symbols, positioning, line-spacing

I would like to use a curved arrow symbol, positioned downwards, to signify "continued on the next line". I'm adjusting the arrow's size using `scalefnt` and taking the symbol indirectly from `mnsymbol` in order to avoid package conflicts.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{scalefnt}

% in order to not load package "mnsymbol":
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{MnSymbolA}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolA}{m}{n}{
  <-6> MnSymbolA5
  <6-7> MnSymbolA6
  <7-8> MnSymbolA7
  <8-9> MnSymbolA8
  <9-10> MnSymbolA9
  <10-12> MnSymbolA10
  <12-> MnSymbolA12}{}
\newcommand*{\lcurvearrowdown}{\mathrel{\text{\usefont{U}{MnSymbolA}{m}{n}\symbol{187}}}}
\newcommand*{\nextlineref}{\raisebox{-1.25ex}[0pt][0pt]{\scalefont{1.25}\(\lcurvearrowdown\)}}

\begin{document}

This is text at normal size. \nextlineref \\
This is more text. xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

\begin{small}
This is text at small size. \nextlineref \\
This is more text. xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
\end{small}

\end{document}
```

I normally use this symbol to signify "math formula continued on the next line", but this example uses text since this is sufficient to illustrate the issue:

While the symbol scales in a `small` context, **the combination of placement / size / distance to the next line appears incongruent**: it is much closer to the letters "x" in the normal-sized context. **Why is that, and how does one correct this?** Inter-line spacing might play a role here, btw.

(Addendum / minor remark: Just now I realize that the arrow probably shouldn't be visually *that* close to the "x" letters ... anyways, my question still stands in the exact same way, as it's the *consistency* that I'm asking about; what I just noticed can so easily be adjusted through the right combination of the `\scalefont` and `\raisebox` factors, which I won't change in this post, to avoid confusion.)

Comment: By giving `\raisebox` the optional argument of `[0pt]` you are hiding the depth of the arrow symbol.  Is that intentional?  Removing this, opens up the line spacing to allow space.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Should I omit both `[0pt]` arguments? I originally used them to make sure that the displaced arrow symbol doesn't affect line spacing in any way.

Comment: The first `[0pt]` kills the height, the second the depth `[0pt]`.  As you are lowing the symbol, the height is not relevant.  You may as well drop both of the optional arguments.

Comment: @AndrewSwann But I want the effective line height to be unaffected.

Comment: If you do not want to affect the line height, then giving the `[0pt]` options to hide the depth is the correct thing to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason behind the strange behaviour is that you are not ending the paragraphs inside the groups that are affected by the font size switches, so the `\baselineskip` applied is the same as in `\normalsize` and this produces the inconsistency mentioned; as soon as you end the paragraphs inside the groups, the proper value for `\baselineskip` is applied and the problem disappears:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{scalefnt}

% in order to not load package "mnsymbol":
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{MnSymbolA}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolA}{m}{n}{
  <-6> MnSymbolA5
  <6-7> MnSymbolA6
  <7-8> MnSymbolA7
  <8-9> MnSymbolA8
  <9-10> MnSymbolA9
  <10-12> MnSymbolA10
  <12-> MnSymbolA12}{}
\newcommand*{\lcurvearrowdown}{\mathrel{\text{\usefont{U}{MnSymbolA}{m}{n}\symbol{187}}}}
\newcommand*{\nextlineref}{\raisebox{-1.25ex}[0pt][0pt]{\scalefont{1.25}\(\lcurvearrowdown\)}}

\begin{document}

This is text at normal size. \nextlineref \\
This is more text. xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

{\small
This is text at \verb+\small+ size. \nextlineref \\
This is more text. xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\par
}

{\footnotesize
This is text at \verb+\footnotesize+ size. \nextlineref \\
This is more text. xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\par
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way, the font size switches are commands with no arguments, to be used as, for example, `{\small some text\par}` (the braces are to keep the change local and `\par` just in case more than one line is used and the proper value for `\baselineskip` is applied).

Comment: If I have a formula spanning over 4 lines (say) and separated by `\nextlineref \\ `, do I need to apply `\par` only to the very end? If I use `\begin{small}...\end{small}`, do I use `\par` in the same way?

Comment: @user14996 only at the end to make sure the paragraph ends; do *not* use `\begin{small}`... `\end{small}`; use `{\small ... \par}` instead (notice the braces to keep the change local).

Comment: Many thanks. Do I also use `\par` when I have more than one paragraph within `{\small ...}` (that is I have at least one empty line in there)?

Comment: @user14996 No, blank lines end paragraphs by themselves; you only need `\par` to end the last paragraph.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `\hookleftarrow` or  `carriagereturn` (dingbat} as in

```
\newcommand\nextline{\raisebox{-1.25ex}[0pt][0pt]{$\hookleftarrow$}}
\newcommand\nextlines{\raisebox{-1ex}[0pt][0pt]{\small\carriagereturn}}
```

A MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{dingbat}
%\usepackage{scalefnt}
\newcommand\nextline{\raisebox{-1.25ex}[0pt][0pt]{$\hookleftarrow$}}
\newcommand\nextlines{\raisebox{-1ex}[0pt][0pt]{\small\carriagereturn}}

\begin{document}

This is text at normal size. \nextline \\
This is more text. xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\par

\begin{small}
This is text at small size. \nextline \\
This is more text. xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\par
\end{small}

\begin{footnotesize}
This is text at footnote size. \nextline \\
This is more text. xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\par
\end{footnotesize}

This is text at normal size. \nextlines \\
This is more text. xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\par

\begin{small}
This is text at small size. \nextlines \\
This is more text. xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\par
\end{small}

\begin{footnotesize}
This is text at footnote size. \nextlines \\
This is more text. xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\par
\end{footnotesize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You're code exhibits the same problem than the one mentioned in the question; you are not ending the paragraph inside the groups, so the wrong `\baselineskip` value is applied.

Comment: How to obtain other kinds of arrows was not part of the question and it's not relevant to the question asked; your answer reproduces the exact problem the OP was asking for, without explaining the cause nor giving a solution.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: OK I think I overlooked. Corrected now.

Comment: @PeterGrill Thanks to Harish Kumar for drawing attention to `dingbat`'s `\carriagereturn`. That's good to know, though `mnsymbol`'s `\lcurvearrowdown` has higher resolution when one zooms in. I suspect that `dingbat` is a bitmap font and that's why. // And thanks to both Harish and Peter for your solutions. Credit for solving the riddle goes to Gonzalo, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the usual *overkill*  option of `tikz` which then gives you all the flexibility inherent in `tikz` in terms of adjusting the arrow tips, colors, line styles, etc.  A few of the options are illustrated below:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\NextLineRef}[1][]{%
    \tikz [overlay,remember picture] \draw [->, out=-10, in=20, distance=0.25cm, thick, #1] 
        (0,0.5ex) to (0,-1.25ex);
}

\begin{document}

This is text at normal size. \NextLineRef[red] \\
This is more text. xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

This is text at normal size. \NextLineRef[red, -latex, shorten >= -0.5ex] \\
This is more text. xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx


{\small
This is text at \verb+\small+ size. \NextLineRef[orange, -latex, distance=1.5cm] \\
This is more text. xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\par
}

{\footnotesize
This is text at \verb+\footnotesize+ size. \NextLineRef[blue, densely dotted] \\
This is more text. xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\par
}

{\small
This is text at \verb+\small+ size. \NextLineRef[green, distance=1.5cm, out=5, in=10] \\
This is more text. xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\par
}

\end{document}
```